# Broadcasting a Signal to All threads in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to broadcast a signal from one thread to all other threads in a process. The threads receiving that signal should handle the signal in a signal handler. How can I achieve this?

---

I tried the following code, but it exits by printing User defined signal 1. What's going on?

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <pthread.h>

const int NTHREADS = 4;

long  prev_fact, i; 

void  SIGhandler(int);     

void  SIGhandler(int sig)
{
  printf("\nThread %lx Received a SIGUSR1.\n", pthread_self());
}

void* tfunc( void* arg )
{
  printf( "Thread %lx executing...\n", pthread_self() );

  while( 1 )
   ;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  pthread_t t[NTHREADS];

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
   pthread_create( &t[i], NULL, tfunc, NULL );

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
   pthread_kill( t[i], SIGUSR1 );

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) 
   pthread_join(t[i], NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works now...

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <pthread.h>

const int NTHREADS = 4;

void  SIGhandler(int);     

void  SIGhandler(int sig)
{
     printf("\nThread %lx Received a SIGUSR1.\n", pthread_self());
}

void* tfunc( void* arg )
{
  printf( "Thread %d(%lx) executing...\n", *((unsigned int*)arg), pthread_self() );

  while( 1 )
    ;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  int tid[NTHREADS];
  pthread_t t[NTHREADS];

  signal(SIGUSR1, SIGhandler);

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
  {
    tid[i] = i;
    pthread_create( &t[i], NULL, tfunc, tid+i );
  }

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
    pthread_kill( t[i], SIGUSR1 );

  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) 
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the way you've written this, it doesn't signal the main thread itself (use `pthread_self()` in the main thread to obtain its thread handle).

Answer (score 4):

The portable pthreads way to do this is to loop around all of the threads, executing `pthread_kill()` for each one.  This requires you to maintain a list of all the `pthread_t` values representing each thread in the process.

On Linux, you can read `/proc/self/task` to determine the TIDs of every thread in the current process, then use `tgkill()` to signal them (use the result of `getpid()` as the `tgid` parameter to `tgkill()`).

Note that glibc does not provide a wrapper for `tgkill()` - you must call it using `syscall()`.

Comment: I tried the following code, but it exits by printing User defined signal 1. What's going on? 

void  SIGhandler(int sig)
{
     printf("\nThread %lx Received a SIGUSR1.\n", pthread_self());
}

void* tfunc( void* arg )
{
  printf( "Thread %lx executing...\n", pthread_self() );
  
  while( 1 )
    ;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  pthread_t t[NTHREADS];
 
  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
    pthread_create( &t[i], NULL, tfunc, NULL );
  
  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
    pthread_kill( t[i], SIGUSR1 );
  
  for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) 
    pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
  
  return 0;
}

Comment: I've added to the code to the answer below. Could you kindly tell me what is going wrong in it?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: You must register your signal handling function using `sigaction()`.  You only need to do this once, because signal disposition is shared across all threads.